# CakePHP 3.x Access Images from URL

Tags: php, html, mod-rewrite, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

CakePHP Version: 3.6
System: Windows 10 WampServer 3.1.3 (Apache)

I'm having trouble accessing images from url i.e. if I type:
http://www.n.co.nz/img/someimage.png I get a 404 not found. I was definitely able to do this in CakePHP 2.0 can't get it working in CakePHP 3.6.

The image "someimage.png" is stored in project/webroot/img/someimage.png

I can access css files directly via url i.e.
http://n.co.nz/css/template_pages.css

Images are loading fine when using the cakePHP way i.e.

`<?= $this->Html->image('someimage.png'); ?>`

Any ideas? Is this a .htaccess or routing issue? My .htaccess are as follows

SourceFiles/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Webroot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Update

In response to Peshraw, here's the contents of my 'App' array in the config/app.php file:

```
'App' => [
    'namespace' => 'App',
    'encoding' => env('APP_ENCODING', 'UTF-8'),
    'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_US'),
    'defaultTimezone' => env('APP_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE', 'UTC'),
    'base' => false,
    'dir' => 'src',
    'webroot' => 'webroot',
    'wwwRoot' => WWW_ROOT,
    //'baseUrl' => env('SCRIPT_NAME'),
    'fullBaseUrl' => false,
    'imageBaseUrl' => 'img/',
    'cssBaseUrl' => 'css/',
    'jsBaseUrl' => 'js/',
    'paths' => [
        'plugins' => [ROOT . DS . 'plugins' . DS],
        'templates' => [APP . 'Template' . DS],
        'locales' => [APP . 'Locale' . DS],
    ], 
];
```

In response top Dave

The HTML that cake is generating when inserting an image the cake way is:

```
<img src="/img/nad_home_logo.png" id="nad_top_logo" alt="">
```

Comment: That is interesting. I am an experienced cakephp 3 programmer and that should definitely work. Your htaccess is fine. can you show me what is inside the array in config/app.php on the line starts with ` App' => [ ` Are you sure you don't have typo in filename? Also letter case may matter.

Comment: "Images are loading fine when using the CakePHP way" - what URL is that generating?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help, I added some extra code to answer your questions

Comment: Hi @codine, can you please share your routes.php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Peshraw H. Ahmed

> Are you sure you don't have typo in filename?

Nope... I added png instead of jpg for the image. CakePHP was telling me the below when trying to load the image directly using the URL

> Error: ImgController could not be found. Error: Create the class
>   ImgController below in file: src\Controller\ImgController.php

This threw me off, I thought cake wasn't routing the image resource calls to the webroot/img folder. I guess it was scanning that folder, not finding the resource and then propagating to see if there's an imgController that knows what to do?

Thanks for the help!